# Systemd mount with a condition

Tags: boot, mount, systemd, ntfs

What I would like to do is mount my ntfs data partition during boot process with systemd only if laptop is on AC power. At the moment I am running this script as a startup application in cinnamon, but would like mount during boot.

```
#!/bin/sh
state=$(acpi -a | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d- -f1)
if [ $state = 'on' ]; then
    mount -o umask=0002,gid=1000,uid=1000,nodev,nosuid,nofail,x-gvfs-show /dev/sda5 MNT_LOCATION
fi
```

**ANSWER:**

I've [asked](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113979990686674352215/posts/cKBvTBWeTVW?cfem=1) at systemd google+ community and [Ian](https://plus.google.com/u/0/113373824789638496786) answered. There is ConditionACPower= option that you can set. So I mead a .mount file in /etc/systemd/system/ with this option in the [Unit] section and it works, it is **IMPORTANT** to name your .mount file exactly the same as your mount location path, replacing / with - . Here is my .mount file for the refernece:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount data
ConditionACPower=true

[Mount]
What=/dev/sda5
Where=absolute mount path
Type=auto
Options=desired options

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

After you need to run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start YOUR-FILE.mount
```

and enable to start automatically at boot

```
systemctl enable YOUR-FILE.mount
```