# Conditional mounts with systemd

Tags: systemd, mount, automounting, systemd-mount

I wish to utilize several conditions to either do a bind mount or an NFS mount as described below. I have seen (limited) discussion on simple conditional mounts, but I have not seen any examples for using conditions similar to "**(bind) mount X if Y else mount Z**."

Details: I have a USB HDD that I can optionally connect to my laptop and it is automatically mounted upon boot using an /etc/fstab entry like this:

```
/dev/mapper/xusbhdd /path/to/usb/mount  btrfs  nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,noatime,nodiratime,space_cache,compress=lzo,defaults,subvol=/@mysubvol/              0 0
```

Inside that mount point is a folder: `/path/to/usb/mount/my_special_folder`

When that device is mounted, I wish to create a bind mount like this:

```
mount --bind /path/to/usb/mount/my_special_folder /path2/my_special_folder
```

However, if that USB device is **not** connected, but I am connected to my company LAN, I wish to mount an NFS share at that location instead, using an /etc/fstab entry like this:

```
fileserver:/my_special_folder/   /path2/my_special_folder/ nfs     _netdev,defaults,noatime,nodiratime,soft,retrans=6,timeo=20,retry=0,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,proto=tcp   0 0
```

Obviously, I can do all that manually. My question is how to make it **automatic**. If my laptop sees the USB HDD connected, it establishes the desired mount and bind mount. If, instead, the company file server is accessible, it establishes the NFS mount.

I found some clues in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568351/15010

I also found a very old answer (2010) that uses a bash script, which is not the approach I wish to take: [Conditional `mount` in Linux: dev or nfs - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/148537/conditional-mount-in-linux-dev-or-nfs)

I also found a related answer here: [Systemd mount with a condition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332688/15010). However, my requirements are more complex. From that link, I believe I could utilize a unit file similar to this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount my_special_folder from USB HDD
ConditionPathExists=/path2/my_special_folder/NOT_MOUNTED

[Mount]
What=/dev/mapper/xusbhdd
Where=/path/to/usb/mount
Type=auto
Options=nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,noatime,nodiratime,space_cache,compress=lzo,defaults,subvol=/@mysubvol/

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

However, that actually accomplishes nothing for me, because the `fstab` options already mount the USB device if it exists, or skip it without failing.

Therefore, I need a unit file to do the bind mount conditionally and a unit file for the NFS mount with a condition. Furthermore, I need a way to ensure that the NFS share is not mounted if the USB device has already been mounted.

Comment: Can't you simply leave out the fstab stuff altogether? If I understand it correctly systemd "synthesizes" those mount units (whose names also unhelpfully appear in logs and elsewhere, but which you cannot "grasp" via `systemctl` _at all_) and so dropping your own `.mount` units should do the job, no? But cool question. Looking forward to some input from others.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - yes, I am OK with skipping fstab entries and only using unit files. I am studying this article for clues, while hoping for helpful answers here. https://blog.iwakd.de/systemd-fstab-and-bind-mounts-with-options